# How can I react to a riverpod FutureProvider by using ref.listen?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
final nextRouteProvider = FutureProvider<String>((ref) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  bool isAppFreshInstall = StorageManager.instance.isAppFreshInstall();
  if (isAppFreshInstall) {
    return AppRouter.onBoardingPath;
  } else {
    return AppRouter.loginPath;
  }
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen<Future<String>>(nextRouteProvider.future, (_, Future<String> path) async {
      context.go(await path);
    });

    return SplashScreen();
  }
```

The above logic is not working but it works well with StateNotifierProvider.

```
class RootViewNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  RootViewNotifier() : super('/') {
    decideRootView();
  }

  void decideRootView() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    var storageManager = StorageManager.instance;
    if (storageManager.isAppFreshInstall()) {
      state = AppRouter.onBoardingPath;
    } else {
      state = AppRouter.loginPath;
    }
  }
}

final rootViewNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<RootViewNotifier, String>(() => RootViewNotifier());

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen<String>(rootViewNotifierProvider, (, String path) {
      context.go(path);
    });

   return SplashScreen(); 
 }
```

But the better way is to use FutureProvider which is not working in this case. So what's wrong with my code. How can I use FutureProvider with the same logic?

Answer (score 3):

Listen to `nextRouteProvider` instead of `nextRouteProvider.future`

Like so:

```
ref.listen(
  nextRouteProvider,
  (AsyncValue<String>? _, AsyncValue<String> next) {
      context.go(next.asData!.value);
   },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The future provider is not intended to be used to notify changes. it is used only to notify when the data is  ready from an async source. Instead, to be notified, the only solution is the notifier provider, and to use it with async data:

```
Future<int> fetch() aynsc => 42;
class Whatever extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<int>> {    
    Whatever(): super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {        
        _fetch();
    }
    Future<void> _fetch() async {
        state = const AsyncValue.loading();
        state = await AsyncValue.guard(() => fetch());    
    }
}
```